# upload blob to azure blob storage via react app

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage, spfx

hello im new with azure storage and spfx . I have built a image generate app using canvas and I want to upload the blob output to storage. Every article I've seen talks about uploading files to azure storage and not blob. 
Maybe someone can direct me to a relevant article, react library documentation or tutorial.
i have azure storage account and spfx web part . 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a sample about upload file to azure blob with react, you could refer to this blog:[Upload to Azure Blob Storage with React](https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-react-34f37805fdfc).

It just uses the [@azure/storage-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) to manage the blobs, so actually you also could refer to this official tutorial:[Quickstart: Manage blobs with JavaScript v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs).

Here is the sample is the azure GitHub repository:[Getting started with samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples).